# Inner product for dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

> Suppose we have a Hilbert space $H$. Is there any explicit expression
>   for the inner product on $H^*$ without resorting to Riesz
>   representation theorem?

I am NOT looking for one that uses the polarization identity - surely there must be a more "reasonable" expression?

---

Motivation: In some completely random context, I started with a normed vector space with norm coming from inner product, and was looking at its dual. Embarassingly I couldn't write down its inner product off the top of my head. 
I cannot come up with any "natural" candidate for the inner product, and while Riesz is nice, it certainly feels unncessarily convoluted, and that one should be able to write down a natural, explicit candidate.

A quick search yields [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164529/inner-product-of-a-dual-space), but using polarization identity certainly doesn't help me "understand" what this inner product should really be and is thus quite unsatisfying. It would be nice if one can show me such an expression, or give me a reason why it shouldn't exist. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel that  Riesz representation theorem is not reasonable? Could you please explain in a bit more detail about what kind of answer you're looking for? Also, I might help if you explicitly state the space you're working on.

Comment: @BigbearZzz, my setup is actually general - an inner product space V, not necessarily complete.

As for why I'm trying avoid Riesz, imagine that I start with V as above. I want to talk about the inner product on $V^*$. I can write down the norm on $V^*$ easily and explicitly, but if I want to show that it satisfies the polarization identity, I only know how to do it via the Riesz route, and I cannot write down the inner product purely starting from two elements in $V^*$. Compare this to writing down the norms of $V^*$ - where I have..

Comment: the simple description of $\|f\|_{V^*} = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} |f(x)|$. I still don't know if I can write down a comparably simple expression for inner product.

Comment: If one is working in the most general setting, i.e., an unknown normed space $V$ where the norm is known to satisfy the parallelogram equality, then the polarization formula is the neatest form of describing the inner product by the known norm I know of. (If it weren't, why wouldn't we always use the other, simpler, representation?)

Comment: @JonathanY., forgive my stupidity, but is my situation really as general? I am asking for the inner product of $V^*$, where the inner product of $V$ is considered given - doesn't this restrict the situation a little bit, especially when the alleged inner product of $V^*$ can involve the inner product of $V$?

Comment: Yes, I see no assumptions made regarding $V$ beyond its having the structure of an inner-product space. Can you clarify in what ways you want $V^*$ described? (That is, if we refrain from assuming completeness. Can you comfortably describe the completion of $V$? We do know that $V^*=\overline{V}^* = \overline{V}$.)

Comment: @JonathanY., I am asking for an expression of the inner product on $V^*$. When you directly write down $V^* = \overline{V}$ I guess you are always describing (perhaps even defining) the inner product on $V^*$ via Riesz. My question is really about whether this can be avoided, other than using polarization; I want a direct description of inner product of two bounded linear functionals on $V$ (as it is, not transporting back to $V$ via Riesz). Using the inner product on $V$ to describe that on $V^*$ is fine.

Comment: One way to phrase my question is: it's easy to define the norm on $V^*$ via the norm on $V$ - is there a way to define the inner product on $V^*$ via the inner product on $V$, "easier" than polarization? It seems implicitly from your answer that it's "no", and you seem to infer that my setting is as general as the "unknown normed space $V$,..." setting you mentioned in your first comment. I am really slow right now, but I still don't see how these two settings are equivalent, given that I am willing to use the inner product on $V$, not just the norm on $V$, in whatever description I may have.

Comment: Are you comfortable with expressing it using complete orthonormal systems (e.g., $\langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(e_n)\overline{g(e_n)}$)? I can't say "yes" or "no" because I don't feel the question has clear boundaries; without clearly defining what type of presentation qualifies, I can only say that "I can't think of anything".

Comment: @JonathanY., I guess using complete orthonormal system would be closest to what I hope for right now. Thanks! If you put it as an answer I will accept it.